# Problema con inserción sql

Tags: php, mysql

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Tengo un objeto ***Usuario*** que por supuesto, me modela un usuario que luego voy a insertar en mi base de datos.

```
<?php
    class Usuario{
        private $usuario;
        private $password;
        private $email;

        ............
    }
```

Esta tabla de usuario solo contiene la contraseña del usuario, el nombre de usuario y el mail. Y esa misma tabla, tiene una relación de 1 a 1 con otra donde se encuentran sus datos personales (Telefono, domicilio, etc).

```
<?php

    class Datos{
        private $domicilio;
        private $telefono;
        private $celular;
        private $user_id;
        .....
    }
```

El tema es el siguiente: cuando el usuario se registra, creo una nueva instancia de Usuario (**new Usuario()**) y seteo sus valores con los datos que ingreso el usuario. Lo mismo hago con datos (**new Datos()**). Ahora, cuando voy a hacer la inserción, tengo un problema. Por que no puedo asociar los datos del usuario a priori por no tener su id. Entonces lo que hago es, primero inserto el usuario (usuario, contraseña, email), luego vuelvo a buscar a ese usuario por su email, y obtengo su id. Con su id, recién ahí puedo insertar los datos para que queden vinculados a ese usuario.
No sé si me exprese correctamente, pero espero que me ayuden.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Como tal problema no le veo; estás haciendo lo procedente para el escenario que tienes. Ya sea lo hagas en un PHP o mediante StoreProcedure siempre tendrás que obtener el ID (que mencionas) para relacionar los datos que insertas en otra tabla. Salvo todos los datos los coloques en misma tabla.

Comment: _Esta tabla de usuario solo contiene la contraseña del usuario, el nombre de usuario... esa misma tabla, tiene una relación de 1 a 1 con **otra** donde se encuentran sus datos personales (Telefono, domicilio...)_ Me pregunto si no has cometido un error de diseño, tratando como dos entidades diferentes una misma entidad. O sea, **un usuario es un usuario**, y los datos suelen ser únicos en cada usuario. No entiendo por qué usas dos tablas. Para los datos que puedan repetirse, como direcciones, lugar de nacimiento, etc. creas una columna del tipo id en la tabla usuarios que sería clave foránea.

Comment: @A.Cedano En que casos entonces usarías una relación de 1 a 1 ? Lo hice por un tema de tener mejor organizado los datos. En el ejemplo, datos tiene 4 atributos, pero en realidad en mi programa tiene 9 atributos, y por un tema de legibilidad tome la decisión de dividirlo de esa forma. Gracias por tu aporte de todas maneras.

Comment: En realidad las relaciones 1:1 son muy raras. Un caso típico sería: tabla **1** llamada **usuarios** en la cual supongamos que hay 5 millones de registros y tabla **2** llamada **perfiles_usuario**. De los 5 millones de la tabla 1 sólo unos 500 registros tendrían perfil de usuario. En ese caso estableces una relación 1:1 entre las tablas 1 y 2. De ese modo evitas en la tabla 1 valores nulos para 4,999,500 registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP provee varias formas de obtener el id de la última inserción:

Por ejemplo

```
<?php
  /* estilo por procedimiento */
  mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
 $ultimo_id = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

 /* orientado a objetos */
 $mysqli->query($query);
 $ultimo_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

 /* sentencias preparadas */
 $sentencia->execute();
 $ultimo_id = $sentencia->insert_id;
?>
```

Estos métodos o funciones son válidos solo si la columna tiene el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT.

Todos estos métodos y alguno más que no he puesto requieren que sean llamados después de ejecutar la cunsulta y antes de ejecutar alguna otra consulta, pues retorna el AUTO_INCREMENT modificado de la última consulta hecha en la conexión.

Puedes guardar el id en una propiedad del objeto Usuario para reutilizarla posteriormente.